# Publish múltiplos projetos no Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Como faço para publicar vários projetos web independentes que estão dentro de uma mesma solution usando o Visual Studio 2012? Geralmente clico com botão direito do mouse no projeto e vou em "Publish" mas não consigo fazer isso com vários proj selecionados.Tem como?

Quero apontar para uma pasta de saída e gerar um pasta interna para cada projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que eu saiba, não tem solução directa. 
As opções que encontrei ou é por Powershell:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/09/22/web-publish-how-to-automate-multi-project-publish-with-file-system/

Ou com macros no visual studio (é preciso adicionar a extensão):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404233(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Depois de muitas busca também cheguei a conclusão de que não há um caminho direto, mas esses exemplos que você mandou servem bem. Vou seguir por aí mesmo. Valeu